# Google Sheets: Extrapolate data from tabs with different columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to narrow down how to join or combine related data from two different tabs that exist in one google sheet.

Tab 1: groups-users

```
+-------------+---------+  
|    group    | user    |  
+-------------+---------+  
| Blue        |   Ana   |  
| Blue        |   Jon   |  
| Blue        |   Ben   |  
| Red         |   Ana   |  
| Red         |   Ben   |  
| Green       |   Sue   |  
| Green       |   Jon   |  
| Green       |   Ben   |  
+-------------+---------+
```

Tab 2  group-repos

```
+-------------+---------+  
|    group    |   repo  |  
+-------------+---------+  
| Blue        |  code   |  
| Blue        |  script |  
| Blue        |   web   |  
| Red         |   code  |  
| Red         |  script |  
| Red         |   web   |  
| Red         |  form   |  
| Green       |  script |
| Green       |  tools  |  
+-------------+---------+
```

What I need to quickly know is Which Repos does Ana have access to?

At a glance from this sample, I see that Ana has access to repos code, script, web, and form because she belongs to groups Blue and Red. And that Sue only has access to repos script and tools because she's only part of group Green.   But the actual data I have in front of me is a couple of hundred lines long per Tab.

I've done some web searching, and the QUERY function keeps popping up, but I haven't ran into any examples that addresses this scenario.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with it in this link.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZVnyRklT7iM_AX2Yr39o3G5u-3hAWPM4l_eYbsisyEY/edit#gid=0

You can see in cell G1 is this formula:

=arrayformula(unique(if(regexmatch(join(",",filter(D:D,E:E=F1)),A1:A10),B1:B10,)))

What it does is filter for the specific person (chosen by the dropdown).
Then it joins all groups that the person is part of together with commas. The regexmatch searches to see if the values from the second table match the values found in the joined string. If they are found, then I return the repo, otherwise I do nothing. I then have a unique function wrapping around everything just to get rid of any repeat repos.

Comment: Wow~ I wouldn't have thought of doing it that way!! That's a nice simple solution to get the information quickly.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: at the risk of further taxing your know-how... what if we throw a wrench into it and also wants to add permissions info?  Would I use a concatenate within that arrayformula?  or perhaps just another array in the following column that uses the produced data to match the permissions?  I updated the google doc posted above with a new tab called permissions scenario.  (PS: I'm such a google sheets function newbie~ I sincerely appreciate the help as I learn!)

Comment: Just realized that I can't do this with the UNIQUE in place since different groups have different permissions per repo.  Removing the UNIQUE and replacing the final column listed sort of gets me there for a quick -if not visually pleasing- answer.      <sigh>    I have so much to learn

Comment: Everything you did was great so far! You could also return B2:C instead of just B instead of creating the two formulas. But that doesn't make it more visually pleasing. What would you want it to look like? If you make a table that would be your end goal, I can look at it again!

Comment: Awesome!  I should've realized that I could expand to include C column.  I've cleaned up the google sheet (hid our initial data and worked from separate tabs which include a concatenated column for slightly cleaner results).
As far as what I would like it to look like, it's at the mercy of the complex data (and the multiple groups / repos / permissions per user). Take a peek and let me know if you think of anything to improve it. 
My head is swimming, but I've learned a lot today and have a decent little sheet to quickly display data.  Thanks times a million.

Comment: That looks so nice!!! I can't reeally think of a way to clean up the sheet more, but I can help with using arrayformula to clean up some of the concat formulas. I put the formulas in column E for the first two tabs. I always prefer to have one formula over dragging other formulas down, especially if you have large chunks of data. Let me know if you have any questions! I love talking about formulas as I'm sure you can tell :D

Comment: cool beans~   this is starting to come together in my head nicely.   I peeked at that column E in the first two tabs;  and if I'm following your logic, it seems like you meant to reference column B for the results?   in lieu of D (since D is the CONCAT)
`=arrayformula(if(row(B1:B)=1,"User & Role",if(B:B="",,B:B&" ("&left(C:C,4)&")")))`

I made the update in column F of the first tab (group-users)

Comment: related but more complex question: How do I array/query for Teams per Repo with its concatenated permission?  
To better visualize, please see tab 4 _curr-queries_, cell K2 (it calls to new tabs 5 and 6).  
The issue I'm having is that I cannot seem to yield a true UNIQUE response in column K to reflect the team with permission per selected repo.